# How to get a fail in DAX if one of the rows in the order fails

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get a column where it comes up as a true or false if one of the lines fails.

Eg,

```
Order Number | Number  |Weight |Fail/Pass Line | Fail Total
123             1          1          P               F
123             2          0          F               F
123             3          10         p               F
125             1          0          f               F
125             2          0          f               F
126             1          5          P               p 
126             2          0.1        P               P
126             3          2          P               P
```

Im trying to get a

> Fail Total

based on Weight, so if any of the lines for the Order Number fail then Fail Total for the entire order should fail

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to take a `MIN` over order. Something like this:

```
Fail Total =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( Orders[Fail/Pass Line] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Orders, Orders[Order Number] )
)
```

The `MIN` takes the first one alphabetically and the `ALLEXCEPT` removes all the filter context except for `Order Number`.